# How can I extract date from CalendarView and display selected date?

Tags: android

Currently I am using code below and I can get current date to be dispalyed in Text field. However I have no idea how to display selected date.

I also used DatePicker and it displays selected date fine, however I would prefer CalendarView.  Thanks

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String currentdate= ss.format(date);
        TextView editText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
        editText.setText(currentdate);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: If user selects the date on CalendarView I want to store it in variable and show it in next activity, So user can get the message you selected this date 25-04-2012

Comment: pass it into the intent extra when you call your next activity. Otherwise, learn how to use startActivityForResult

Comment: That is not the problem, but how can I extract date from CalendarView and display selected date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in onCreate :

```
 CalendarView v = new CalendarView( this );
 v.setOnDateChangeListener( new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
       this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar( year, month, dayOfMonth );
    }//met
 });
```

Comment: I am getting error for this.calendar

calendar cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 3):

```
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(this);
setContentView(view);

view.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView arg0, int year, int month,
        int date) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date+ "/"+month+"/"+year,4000).show();
    }
});
```

This will display the user selected date.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

`Calendar` is different from [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html). `CalendarView` is a descendant of `View` so it has many event handlers, like an [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). Perhaps this is what you are trying to find?

Comment: would something like this work:

CalendarView calendarmy = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);

Answer (score 0):

```
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(this);
setContentView(view);

view.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView arg0, int year, int month,
        int date) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date+ "/"+month+"/"+year,4000).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple `Kotlin` code to get selected date from `CalenderView`:**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Toast Selected Date" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.CalendarView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.testandcheck.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding   // Binding object for ViewBinding.

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    // Set date change listener on calenderView.
    // Callback notified when user select a date from CalenderView on UI.
    binding.calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener { calView: CalendarView, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->

        // Create calender object with which will have system date time.
        val calender: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

        // Set attributes in calender object as per selected date.
        calender.set(year, month, dayOfMonth)

        // Now set calenderView with this calender object to highlight selected date on UI.
        calView.setDate(calender.timeInMillis, true, true)
        Log.d("SelectedDate", "$dayOfMonth/${month + 1}/$year")
    }

    // Example button to show get selected date from CalenderView and show in Toast.
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {

        // Fetch long milliseconds from calenderView.
        val dateMillis: Long = binding.calendarView.date

        // Create Date object from milliseconds.
        val date: Date = Date(dateMillis)

        // Get Date values and created formatted string date to show in Toast.
        val selectedDayOfWeek = DateFormat.format("EEEE", date) as String // Monday
        val selectedDay = DateFormat.format("dd", date) as String // 05
        val selectedMonthString = DateFormat.format("MMM", date) as String // Jul
        val selectedMonthNumber = DateFormat.format("MM", date) as String // 6 --> Month Code as Jan = 0 till Dec = 11.
        val selectedYear = DateFormat.format("yyyy", date) as String // 2021

        val strFormattedSelectedDate = "$selectedDay-${selectedMonthNumber + 1}-$selectedYear ($selectedDayOfWeek)"
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Selected Date = $strFormattedSelectedDate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

}
```

> **Note**: Once you select any date on `CalenderView` it will just highlight that day but not select. Due to this reason you will always get system's current date-time when you call `calendarView.date` (kotlin)  or  `calenderView.getDate()` (Java). So you have to implement the `setOnDateChangeListener`. Upon receiving callback, you have to programmatically set the new `Date` object as shown.

*Hope it helps...... Happy Coding...... :)*

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();
    String currentdate= ss.format(date);
    TextView editText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
    editText.setText(currentdate);
```

above one is ur code try below code

```
CalendarView cv = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.cv1);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat ss = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date(cv);
    String currentdate= ss.format(date);
    TextView editText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textfield1);
    editText.setText(currentdate);
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of what you did to resolve the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Date date=new Date(cv); has been deprecated.

Comment: Why have you passed cv inside date constructor?