# How to get the modify date of calendar event?

Tags: java, android

I need to get the modify date of calendar event, but I can't find an appropriate field in [Events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html) table.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339808/how-can-i-extract-date-from-calendarview-and-display-selected-date

Comment: @Audi Thands for your reply, but the question is about [CalendarContract](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).